# How can I mount a Windows 7 disk image on the same system? (signature conflict)

Tags: windows-7, mount, disk-image, vhd

In another [recent post](https://superuser.com/questions/1077113/how-should-i-back-up-my-data-before-a-windows-re-install-omitted-files-when-cop) on superuser.com I asked how to back up all of my files on a Windows 7 system before reboot. It was advised to create a disk image using [disk2vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx).

I did so but when I mount the image in computer management under Windows 7 (i.e. in the same system that is backed up), the drive mounts but is listed as "offline" with additional information that there is a signature conflict with another disk (presumably the system drive that I want to back up).

So my question is, if I want to create a full disk image as back up of *all* of my files, how can I mount the `.vhd` under the same system. This should be possible because otherwise it is not a good back up solution I suppose.

**Edit**: [This TechNet post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2011/11/06/fixing-disk-signature-collisions/) seems relevant, where it is discussed that it is problematic to mount a `vhd` to the same system it images. I understand the problem, but perhaps then the disk image is not a good back up plan after all.

Comment: Wow... would be interesting to know why somebody downvoted.

Comment: Okay. Now we're back to zero.

Comment: Funny this down voting without clear arguments why it's a bad question. May be helpful to solve it actually.

Comment: down votes?...
Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please. Also votes are based on how useful and clear the question is. Which I think you have met those requirements as of you edit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having issues is that you are breaking the license agreement by using the same license key on both physical and virtual systems.

You might be able to bypass this problem with [Sysprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx), or similar tool.

Disk are fine for backups, but not in the way you are using it.

Comment: Thanks, can you specify how to use them?

Comment: @tomka You are making a *virtual hard disk*, which is similar to a traditional disk image in some respects, yet different - and is the source of your problems.  There are many disk imaging tools out there I use [Comodo](https://www.comodo.com/home/backup-online-storage/comodo-backup.php) that will make disk image backups.